# Why do Java IDE's default implementation templates not throw AssertionErrors?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

When you generate/overwrite new methods, generate try-catch constructs etc. in IDEs, most of them (like Eclipse, Intellij) default to rather questionable behavior like returning null, printing stacktrace and continuing, calling super method etc. For example, if you autocomplete on 'Thread.sleep(x)', the IDE will give you:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(x);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It seems to me that a more sensible thing to do would be `throw new AssertionError(e)` in this case, and `throw new AssertionError("not implemented")` in other cases.

Comment: It's up to you to change it to whatever you want it to do. It's configurable.

Comment: @maba: Yeah, but why set a bad one as default?

Comment: @EnnoShioji to force you to come up with a better one yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer as to why their isn't a "better" default is that it can be entirely subjective as to what that "better" one would be :)

Here's how to configure in IntelliJ:

Settings -> [IDE Settings] File and Code Templates -> [tab: Code] `Catch Statement body`

enter: `throw new AssertionError("not implemented");`

Hope this helps.